# How to access internals of dialogs, created by WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, windowbuilder

It seems to me, that WindowBuilder dialogs are created as things in itseves. I.e. all components are present as local variables in constructor. So, no way to access, initialize or read, data inside them.

Why so?

Answer (score 0):

That is just the default scope as generated by WindowBuilder.  If you want to access the components from, for example, another method within your class, you could always change the code from:

```
public Test_class() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Object created within the constructor
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

To something more like:

```
private JPanel panel;
public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

After you do that, you will be able to call methods such as `panel.add(Component)` from any method called later in your code.  You could also change the modifier to `public` and then call methods by using `Test_class().panel.method()`